Varchar str_to_date incorrect datetime value
I had issues importing a CSV into my MySQL table because I could not get the DATE or DATETIME fields working.  I tried using LOAD DATA INFILE but was having no success.
So I changed any DATE or DATETIME fields to VARCHAR, and all of my data finally loaded.
But now I need to update the dates in the VARCHAR fields to just show the date format like this:
yyyy-mm-dd

So I tried to run this query:
UPDATE `table` SET 
  `CreatedDate` = STR_TO_DATE(CreatedDate, '%Y-%M-%D'), 
  `LastClickDate` = STR_TO_DATE(LastClickDate, '%Y-%M-%D'), 
  `LastOpenDate` = STR_TO_DATE(LastOpenDate, '%Y-%M-%D'), 
  `LastSendDate` = STR_TO_DATE(LastSendDate, '%Y-%M-%D'), 
  `LastUnsubscribeDate` = STR_TO_DATE(LastUnsubscribeDate, '%Y-%M-%D')

But I am getting the below error:
Incorrect datetime value: '6/25/2024 5:19:22 PM' for function str_to_date

The database table dates columns have a similar structure as the below:
ColumnName: CreatedDate 
Type: varchar(30)
Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci
Attributes: Yes
Default: NULL

How can I get the above query to work so that the dates can display in a yyyy-mm-dd format?

You're mixing up STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_FORMAT().
STR_TO_DATE() parses a string that contains a non-standard datetime format.
DATE_FORMAT() assumes the input is a properly formatted MySQL datetime, and outputs a specified format, which may be non-standard.
You have non-standard strings, so STR_TO_DATE() is the correct function to use, but you have to tell it what format the string currently has.
Example:
mysql> select str_to_date('6/25/2024 5:19:22 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p') as proper_datetime;
+---------------------+
| proper_datetime     |
+---------------------+
| 2024-06-25 17:19:22 |
+---------------------+

Notice my format string '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p' matches the current format of your string (refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format for reference documentation for the format codes).
The output of STR_TO_DATE() is automatically in MySQL standard datetime format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
If you want to format it without the time portion, you use DATE_FORMAT() on the result of the STR_TO_DATE():
mysql> select date_format(str_to_date('6/25/2024 5:19:22 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p'), '%Y-%m-%d') as proper_date;
+-------------+
| proper_date |
+-------------+
| 2024-06-25  |
+-------------+

Or you could cast it to the DATE type:
mysql> select date(str_to_date('6/25/2024 5:19:22 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) as proper_date;
+-------------+
| proper_date |
+-------------+
| 2024-06-25  |
+-------------+


I can use the queries you provided to SELECT as indicated.  But I'm having an issue writing it as an UPDATE query.  How can I use DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE()) in an UPDATE query?

Never mind.  I figured it out.  I was able to do this: UPDATE table SET CreatedDate = date(str_to_date(CreatedDate, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%i:%s %p')) and that converted all the datetimes to just the date.  Thank you.

Still having problems on other date columns.  I'll probably have to ask another question.

If your data is in multiple non-standard formats, then one pattern may not work for all of them. You might have to do multiple UPDATEs.
